# Why are arguments of fopen restrict-qualified?

Tags: c

It has caught my attention that both arguments of `fopen` are both `restrict`-qualified. It's been that way since C99.

What does this achieve?

If I have:

```
const char *path = "foobar";
const char *mode = path + 5;

FILE *f = fopen(path, mode);
```

is the behavior undefined, since the `mode` pointer accesses
something which is also accessed through `path`?

What if the code is this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("foobar", "r");
```

The arguments are treated as immutable by `fopen`, so I can't think of what benefit `restrict` achieves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be that this is presentation flaw in the standard, but one that has no consequences.

Firstly, `restrict` qualifiers on function parameters are not part of the function type. A declaration with `restrict` qualifiers is compatible with a definition that lacks them, and vice versa.

Secondly, `restrict` qualifiers in a declaration do not confer any semantics to a declaration; effectively, they do not matter.

For all the functions described in the Library clause in the standard, which do not accept overlapping objects, that restriction is explicitly stated in the semantic description. For some others, the restriction can be inferred from type aliasing rules or other common sense. Like:

```
void setbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
     char * restrict buf);
```

It's not because of the `restrict` here that we don't want `stream` and `buf` to overlap, but because they have different types, and not to mention it would be catastrophic for the stream object to be using itself as the I/O buffer.

In the case of `memcpy` and `memmove`, the former is shown with `restrict`, the latter without. But, again, this is just a decoy. It's the description of `memcpy` that rules out overlapping objects, not the `restrict`, which has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be any actual benefit to using `restrict` in *this* declaration because, as you say, nothing exciting ever happens to *these* two strings. But `restrict` in general is an extremely valuable addition to the language because there are situations where it *does* save you lots of effort; and it is far better to get into the habit of using it everywhere *except* the rare cases where things really *do* overlap, than not to use it by default and try to guess where it would yield a benefit. Such guesses are usually wrong, and can easily be forgotten.

Comment: I'm not able to agree. Adding `restrict` to a correct program can remove the definition of behavior where it was previously defined. It is a risky optimization tool whereby the programmer communicates to the compiler that the program has certain properties, which are not verified by that compiler to be true, and according to which the program may be blindly optimized.  The overwhelming preference should be to avoid introducing anything like that, except where it provides a benefit (preferrably measurable).

Comment: If there really is not benefit in `restrict` qualifiers in `fopen`, it's criminal for them to be there, since all they do is potentially cause undefined behavior.

Comment: For example, memcpy has restrict-qualified pointer arguments. Before that, the C standard said "memcpy between overlapping pointers is undefined behaviour". And it would in practice "go wrong". Now the restrict qualification makes it undefined behaviour, so practically nothing has changed, but the undefined behaviour is now more obvious.

Comment: @gnasher729 But what you're saying here is not actually true. Nothing has changed at all. The standard still says that the overlapping `memcpy` is undefined behavior, using words, and not using `restrict`.   Only a *definition* of `memcpy` that uses `restrict` will have the property that the behavior is undefined. The standard doesn't offer a definition, only a declaration. The declaration has `restrict`, but it means nothing; `fopen` also has `restrict` and it does allow the mode and filename to overlap.  **Qualifiers on parameters in a declaration are ignored.**